# "Je me suis perdu" ou "Je me suis perdue"?

Tags: accord

Je vois souvent l'écriture de "Je me suis perdue", mais c'est toujours une femme qui l'écrit.

Si je suis un homme, je dois écrire "je me suis perdu" ou "je me suis perdue"?

Comment: "Je me suis perdu" est correct (du point de vue d'un homme!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comme le fait remarquer Laure en commentaire, *"se perdre"* est un verbe pronominal. Au participe passé **il s'accorde donc avec le sujet**.

Si je suis un homme: *"je me suis perdu"*; et si je suis une femme: *"je me suis perdue"*. De la même manière, au pluriel : *"nous nous sommes perdus"* ou *"nous nous sommes perdues"*.